# How set the server name of postgres using docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Let's say I want a docker-compose.yml that sets 2 services : a postgresql server and [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) (a kind of phpmyadmin).
If I declare

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services :
    myservername:
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    admin:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 8080:8080
```

With a `docker-compose up -d` and then on [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) I can connect to postgres :

[image: docker-compose set with "myservername" for database service]

That works like a charm. Perfect. But....

But due to specific configurations files in my project, I need that the postgres server name be `localhost`. So I tried :

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services :
    localhost: # <----- that's the change
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    admin:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

And when I try to connect :
`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Address not available Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`
[image: docker-compose set with "localhost" for database service]

Any idea ?

Comment: Change your configuration to match the host name of the database server, not _vice versa_.  `localhost` has a pretty specific technical meaning and you can't make things that aren't the current container/host be `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make this work using dockers host network mode, where containers use the hosts network instead of getting their own isolated one, see https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode.

This is something of a security risk though (as containers gets full access to the host network). **SHOULD NOT USE IN PRODUCTION :)**

But something like:

```
version: '3.1'
services :
    myservername:
        network_mode: host
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    admin:
        network_mode: host
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 8080:8080
```